# Responsive css rules using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like some parts of my site to reduce in size on a mobile device. Is it possible to have these changes triggered by bootstrap, instead of manually adding responsive css rules based on page width?

For example, by trial and error I figured out that [bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) switches from fixed-width to variable width and collapsed `navbar` whenever the browser width is smaller than `767px`. I would like some other elements of my page to style simultaneously. Is there a natural/native way to have these changes triggered/inherited from bootstrap responsive rules, instead of manually adding

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px)
```

Comment: Why don't you use some responsive classes that bootstrap provides? Like "col-lg-12", "hidden-sm", etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to incorporate the classes of bootstrap in your code. Additionally use utility classes for showing and hiding content by device. They will hide or show div's at a given screen size with these classes:

```
.visible-phone   
.visible-tablet  
.visible-desktop 
.hidden-phone    
.hidden-tablet   
.hidden-desktop
```

(Phones 767px and below, Tablets 979px to 768px).

Update: this week things have changed, Bootstraps new version has different classes:

Old= .visible-phone    new = .visible-sm

Old= .visible-tablet     new = .visible-md

Old= .visible-desktop   new = .visible-lg

Old= .hidden-phone  new = .hidden-sm

Old= .hidden-tablet new = .hidden-md

Old= .hidden-desktop    new = .hidden-lg

More changes are easily viewed at [the migration guide](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)

Update: the new classes starting with 'visible' have been deprecated in favor of classes that regulate the CSS display property. See [bootstraps explanation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Comment: Just what was looking for, the updated version of these classes, thanks!

Comment: What does the acronyms stand for (`lg`, `sm`, `md`)? Is it large, small & medium?

Comment: Instead of using 'phone', 'tablet', etc. which borders are due to fade (think of tablets that are capable of making phone calls), the classes represent an indication of the size of the device. Yes, large, medium, small. Now also xs, extra small. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes